# Elm - open ended types in a contract

Tags: types, elm, contract

Given the pseudo-contract:

```
condy: Int -> Int -> a -> b
condy n m a b =
  if n == m then a else b
```

how can one define the above contract correctly such that the types of a and b are equal but can be any type? Effectively the above removes the need for the extra function `condyEffect[Type]` for each Type:

```
condyPrime: Int -> Int -> Bool
condy n m =
  n == m

condyEffectInt: Bool -> Int
condyEffectInt bool k l =
  if bool then k else l
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `condy` function would look like this:

```elm
condy: Int -> Int -> a -> a -> a
condy n m a b =
  if n == m then a else b
```

The portion `a -> a -> a` in the type signature just says that the 3rd and 4th parameter of `condy` must be of the same type, and the final `a` in the type annotation says the return value needs to be the same type as the third and fourth parameters.